# How to deserialize below json response in apex salesforce?

Tags: json

```
{
  "SAP2SF": [
    {
      "Account_Customer_Name": "Test123 Test123"
    },
    {
      "Account_Customer_Number": "61381112"
    },
    {
      "Account_Land_Line": "07000000000"
    },
    {
      "Account_Mobile": ""
    },
    {
      "Account_Customer_Email": "test@test.com"
    },
    {
      "Contact": [
        {
          "First_Name": "Test123"
        },
        {
          "Last": "Test123"
        },
        {
          "Land_Line": ""
        },
        {
          "Mobile": ""
        },
        {
          "Email": "test@test.com"
        },
        {
          "np_email": ""
        },
        {
          "np_sms": ""
        },
        {
          "np_tele": ""
        },
        {
          "np_post": ""
        },
        {
          "third_party_email": ""
        },
        {
          "third_party_sms": ""
        },
        {
          "third_party_tele": ""
        },
        {
          "third_party_post": ""
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sites": [
        {
          "Business_Agreement_Number": "00601797699"
        },
        {
          "Contract_Number": "2011585720"
        },
        {
          "Product_ID_Text": "SME_DEF_ELEC_ROB"
        },
        {
          "Contract_Start_Date": ""
        },
        {
          "Contract_End_Date": ""
        },
        {
          "Contract_User_Status": "Live"
        },
        {
          "MPXN": "000000000111209578"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Interest_Flag": ""
    },
    {
      "Refusal_Flag": ""
    },
    {
      "Refusal_Reason": ""
    },
    {
      "Refusal_Opt_out_date": ""
    },
    {
      "Payment_Method": ""
    },
    {
      "DD_Details_Sort_Code": ""
    },
    {
      "DD_Details_Account_Number": ""
    },
    {
      "DD_Details_Agreement_Date": ""
    },
    {
      "DD_Details_Frequency": ""
    },
    {
      "DD_Details_Take_Date": "22"
    },
    {
      "DD_Details_Account_Holdder_Name": ""
    },
    {
      "DD_Details_Bank_Name": ""
    },
    {
      "DD_Details_Branch_Name": ""
    },
    {
      "DD_Details_Account_Balance": "0.00 "
    },
    {
      "DD_Details_Fixed_DD_Amount": "0.00 "
    },
    {
      "DD_Details_Bill_Frequency": ""
    },
    {
      "EAC": ""
    },
    {
      "AQ": ""
    },
    {
      "Billing_Adress": [
        {
          "House_Number": "233"
        },
        {
          "Street_1": "BEVERLEY ROAD"
        },
        {
          "City": "HULL"
        },
        {
          "District": ""
        },
        {
          "Post_Code": "HU5 2UT"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. The aim of this site isn't to write your code for you, but rather help you overcome specific problems to help you become a better programmer/admin. To that end, it helps if you show us the research you've done, and what you've tried so far. This question, for example, is one that you should be able to find the answer for by doing some research first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/ to generate Apex for your JSON object.

```
public class JSON2Apex {

    public class Billing_Adress {
        public String House_Number;
        public String Street_1;
        public String City;
        public String District;
        public String Post_Code;
    }

    public List<SAP2SF> SAP2SF;

    public class SAP2SF {
        public String Account_Customer_Name;
        public String Account_Customer_Number;
        public String Account_Land_Line;
        public String Account_Mobile;
        public String Account_Customer_Email;
        public List<Contact> Contact;
        public List<Sites> Sites;
        public String Interest_Flag;
        public String Refusal_Flag;
        public String Refusal_Reason;
        public String Refusal_Opt_out_date;
        public String Payment_Method;
        public String DD_Details_Sort_Code;
        public String DD_Details_Account_Number;
        public String DD_Details_Agreement_Date;
        public String DD_Details_Frequency;
        public String DD_Details_Take_Date;
        public String DD_Details_Account_Holdder_Name;
        public String DD_Details_Bank_Name;
        public String DD_Details_Branch_Name;
        public String DD_Details_Account_Balance;
        public String DD_Details_Fixed_DD_Amount;
        public String DD_Details_Bill_Frequency;
        public String EAC;
        public String AQ;
        public List<Billing_Adress> Billing_Adress;
    }

    public class Contact {
        public String First_Name;
        public String Last;
        public String Land_Line;
        public String Mobile;
        public String Email;
        public String np_email;
        public String np_sms;
        public String np_tele;
        public String np_post;
        public String third_party_email;
        public String third_party_sms;
        public String third_party_tele;
        public String third_party_post;
    }

    public class Sites {
        public String Business_Agreement_Number;
        public String Contract_Number;
        public String Product_ID_Text;
        public String Contract_Start_Date;
        public String Contract_End_Date;
        public String Contract_User_Status;
        public String MPXN;
    }


    public static JSON2Apex parse(String json) {
        return (JSON2Apex) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JSON2Apex.class);
    }
}
```

After that use below code to de-serialize JSON response.

```
JSON2Apex responseObj=JSON2Apex.parse(jsonString);
```

If you want to use above class's property in lightning use `@AuraEnabled` with each property.